# Dropdownlist for, selection options text (from database) becomes vertically single letter using C# razor

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, loops, dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to create a drop down list for from a dataset column in my SQL Server database. I have successfully linked the data. However, in view, the dropdown list data appears to have a vertically text.

Please see the screen captured below:

[image: As you cab see the captured image the list becomes vertically with single letter becomes an option select]

[image: This is the store procedure, which the dropdown list option should show]

What causes this? Please help!

I'm just going to post the relevant code to easy to see.

Here is the line of the html code (I put index 0 for savedCompCoList for testing only to only get the first row):

```
<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.objBV.objCompCo.SavedCompCoSelected, new SelectList(Model.objBV.objCompCo.SavedCompCoList[0].CompCo_ID_With_date_List), "Select List", new { style = "width: 250px;" }))</div>
```

Using `xmlDocument` for connection to database:

```
public static XmlDocument GetSavedCompCo()
{
    XmlDocument xmlTmp = DatabaseLib.RunStoredProcedure(UDV.spGetSavedCompCoListBV, UDV.connStringUserDB);
  
    return xmlTmp;
}
```

Using Web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetSavedCompCo() { return BDOLibrary_Val_BV.CompsLib.GetSavedCompCo(); }
```

My model - here is the loop that loop though (this may be the cause):

```
public class CompCo
{
        private readonly BDOWebService.BDOWebService webS = new BDOWebService.BDOWebService(); //EC: web service

        //EC: variables
        public List<SavedCompCo> SavedCompCoList { get; set; }
        public int SavedCompCoSelected { get; set; }

        public CompCo()
        {
            initSavedCompCoList();
            Comps = new List<Company>();
        }

        private void initSavedCompCoList()
        {
            SavedCompCoList = new List<SavedCompCo>();
            XmlDocument xmlTmp = webS.GetSavedCompCo();

            XmlNodeList nodeListSavedCompCo_ID_With_Date = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("CompCo_ID_With_Date");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListSavedCompCo_ID_With_Date.Count; i++)
            {
                SavedCompCo SavedCompCoTemp = new SavedCompCo();
                SavedCompCoTemp.CompCo_ID_With_date_List = nodeListSavedCompCo_ID_With_Date[i].InnerText.Trim();

                SavedCompCoList.Add(SavedCompCoTemp);
            }
    
        }
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like `Model.objBV.objCompCo.SavedCompCoList[0].CompCo_ID_With_date_List` is a string. So when you populate a dropdown with single string value, the binding loginc will iterate thru the string and populate indvidual characters as separate items in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Do you want do display/populate only one single date value in the dropdown list?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for the comment. I want to display one single date value like this "1 sept 28 2020 8:17AM" as a string in the dropdown list. I think the index of the string got seprated so it becomes e.g "1"  "sept" . how will I fix this. Thanks

Comment: Problem Solved ! Model should be in list<string> . Thanks